# What should we do with the "counting to potato" challenge?

Tags: discussion, specific-question

A [code golf challenge entitled "Counting to Potato"](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/48952/3808) was recently posted that has become somewhat controversial, as it could be taken as offensive to some people.

What should be done with this question? Should it be...

- deleted outright?
- edited to remove the controversial reference?
- left as is?

Additionally, what should the general policy be on similar, possibly offensive types of challenges?

Comment: Leaving aside the controversial reference, it's closeable as unclear and borderline closeable as dupe of various previous base-conversion questions.

Comment: @PeterTaylor Can you please elaborate? As the poster, I thought the conditions behind the challenge were clear. If not, I am more than willing to clarify. Also, I tried searching for like questions, but I may have missed some. Can you please reference the potential duplicates?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

In this case, I think we can simply edit out the reference. The challenge itself isn't offensive, and you could substitute any word for *POTATO* without changing the task.

"General policy" would follow suit IMO. If a simple edit can remove whatever's causing the offense, then just do it. If there's really no way to remove it, deletion might be a good option, but that should be decided on a case by case basis.

Comment: "If there's really no way to remove it" should probably include the OP's unwillingness to remove the offensive content (I don't know whether that's the case in this instance, but I mean in general).

Comment: Sure. If the OP rolls back edits like this (esp multiple times) after it's been explained in comments/edit notes, then throw down the mod hammer.

Comment: As the OP, I am more than willing to remove the reference. I left it there more for the sake of explaining the inspiration behind the question. It is, in no way, vital to the success of the question.
@MartinBüttner, if you unlock, I will remove the reference.

Comment: @tfitzger done.

Comment: @MartinBüttner Thank you. I have updated the question to remove any references to the offensive meme.

Comment: @tfitzger Thanks for being responsive and doing the right thing (IMO).  My downvote and closevote have been retracted.